# how does the python's membership function work?

Tags: python, scikit-learn, fuzzy

Can someone explain to me what is this `fuzz.trimf(x, [0, 5, 10])` membership taking in, The first one is the range array and in this case that is the '`x`' and what is that `[0,5,10]` for? please explain.

Comment: Have you looked at the documentation? https://pythonhosted.org/scikit-fuzzy/api/skfuzzy.membership.html#skfuzzy.membership.trimf

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The purpose of membership functions are to generalize a function using valuation.

In the case of the `trimf()` function, the membership function being created is triangularly shaped. In order to determine the bounds of the generalization being created based on the actual data, the user must input scalars as constraints on how large or small the user wants the generalization to be.

Those scalars are the second parameter of the `trimf()` function and are represented by the list `[0, 5, 10]`.
If you are familiar with the underlying math, the attached image shows the equation used to determine the value of the membership function.

In the attached image,

- The `a` would be your `0`
- The `b` would be your `5`
- And the `c` would be your `10`.

[image: Triangularly Shaped Membership Equation]

Comment: thank you, I am having a scenario where I am supposed to feed in only two numerical values and get output out of membership function, python has a variety of them, I would be glad and thankful if you suggest me which is to be used.

Comment: If you are only feeding in two values, you are likely being asked to utilize a Gaussian  membership function where the inputs for the `gaussmf()` function are `(x, mean, sigma)` where `x = your data`, `mean = the center point of your distribution`, and `sigma = the standard deviation of your dataset`.

Comment: @ZeeshanHaris If I answered your question please mark the question as answered.